# Doubly linked list using d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have been trying to make a doubly linked list using d3.js. I have tried with chords in d3.js but that did not worked. Can anyone help me with the function in d3.js that can be best fitted for circular linked list.

EDIT : Something like this

[image]

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) Please post a example of the code you used so far. SO is not a site where you can ask for products, but a site where we can help you fix problems.

Comment: @cerbus I am not asking for product. I told that I have tried chord in D3.js. Working example is at - http://bost.ocks.org/mike/uberdata/. Problem is I dont want this links to be in circular loop.

Comment: How do you want your links to be displayed? If you have an idea for how it should look, we might be able to point you towards an example implementation of it.

Comment: @ckersch Image added.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following:

Create an array of data for each of your nodes. Then create an array of links between the nodes. Each link should contain the location of each node.

For each node and link, create a group. For the nodes, add some rects and a text. For the links, add some arrows.

Here's a similar example with circles:

[Directed graph](http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347)

Comment: It was nt exactly what I was looking 4 bt it helpd me a lot so +1 for that